# Time Series Analysis Book/References not from Economists/Econometrics

Tags: time-series, references, spectral-analysis

Are there any time series books not written from an economics/econometrics perspective? I was hoping someone from biostatistics perspective wrote a time-series analysis book where terms like heteroskedasticity isn't used?

I wasn't looking for a mixed-effects or longitudinal analysis text, more on spectral densities and box-cox.

Comment: Hi: peter diggle has a  time-series book that is not economics/econometrics oriented but it's old and I'm not sure it covers what you need. spectral densities are usually given a chapter in any decent time-series book. box-cox is covered in more introductory ts books. Are you looking for a text that covers ONLY spectral densities and nothing else? It's not so clear what you're looking for. Time-series is interdisciplinary ( statistics, EE, )so there are tons of books, besides econometric ones,  but each has its own niche. Also, are you interested in the theoretical aspects  or the applied.

Comment: Shumway and Stoffer: http://amzn.com/3319524518/?tag=otexts-20

Comment: *Applied Longtudinal Analysis* by Singer and Wittinck.   *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierachical Models* by Gelman and Hill.

Comment: @user332577 Singer and Willt's text ***is not*** a time series modeling text. It is a *longitudinal* modeling text (e.g. "let's put time as a variable in the model), by contrast time series models are interested in modeling autocorrelation and moving averages, and are more interested in modeling data generating processes.

Comment: @alexis  We can agree to disagree on your finely nuanced point.